# md-autocomplete input height issue in safari

Tags: angularjs, material-design, angularjs-material

I am using AngularJS v1.5.6 and AngularJS Material Design v1.1.8, md-autocomplete works fine in all browsers except Safari. Height of the input search box is not filled 100%. See below image for reference

Safari Version 12.0.3 (14606.4.5)

[image]

Answer (score -1):

you can add css override the default cssStyle to hack the Safari. such as `input 100%`